# How to fix the game function?

Tags: python, tkinter

im beginner on python and as a practice i want to solve this ( https://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/07/05/18-cows-and-bulls.html ) by tkinter
when i run this code and press start button it hangs and no error is shown in pycharm, even when i debug
obviously the bug is in game code
can you help me with this?

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def entry_box():
    global user_guess
    start_button.destroy()
    user_guess=Entry(win,font='Bradly 12', width=25)
    user_guess.insert(END,'0000')
    user_guess.place(x=150,y=150)
    game()

def game():
    global user_guess , result
    digit=[]
    num =[]
    counter = 0
    for i in range(4):
        digit.append(random.randint(0,9))
    while num != digit:
        num = list(user_guess.get())
        cow = 0
        bull = 0
        for i in range(4):
            if int(num[i]) in digit:
                if int(num[i])==digit[i]:
                    cow += 1
                else:
                    bull += 1
        counter += 1
        result.set('cow = %d \n bull = %d'%(cow,bull))
    result.set('WELL DONE! YOU FOUND IT AFTER %d GUESS ' %counter )

win = Tk()
win.title('Let\'s play')
frame = Frame(win, height=300, width=500, bg='lightblue')
frame.pack()
result = StringVar()
result.set('cow=0\nbull=0')
start_button = Button(win , text='start', font='Broadway 15',command = entry_box)
start_button.place(x=200, y=175)
results = Label(win, textvariable=result, font='Broadway 20',bg='lightblue', fg='darkblue')
results.place(x=200 , y=0)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: "when i debug obviously the bug is in game code", please elaborate what you noticed when debugging. The more precice you are in your error descriptions, the likelier you will get a meaningful answer. Please also include the description of what your code is supposed to do in the body of your question, don't add explanations as off-site resources, otherwise ppl will likely skip your question

Comment: Learn how to use the PyCharm debugger: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html

Comment: in GUI very important is `mainloop()` which runs loop all time - it gets events froms yste, sends them to widgets, update values in widgets, redraw window and all widgets, etc. again and again in loop. If you execut long-running function then it can't go back to mainloop which readraw widgets and you can't see your changes. It looks like it hangs. You can use `win.update()` in your function to force mainloop to redraw widgets. OR you have to change all code and not use `while` loop (or `time.sleep()`) but ie. run some short code only when you click button.

Comment: when I added `win.update()` then I can play but I see two problems. First: `num != digit:` you compare list of chars with list of digits. it will be always False. You would have to convert chars in `num` to `int()`. Second: when I delete on digit in entry to put new one then it gets error when it try to check fourth digit from entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code hangs because of multiple reasons:

- as @furas mentioned, `num != digit` will always be `False`, because you compare list of chars with list of digits;
- Even if you fix this, your code will just never exit the loop: you will compare the first list `[0,0,0,0]` with the random one (`num`) and unless they are equal, you will get `False`. Then the code takes the same two lists, and compares them infinitely, with always the same outcome. You can see this easily if you add a print statement in the `while` loop.

This is one possible solution:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class MainGame(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self, height=300, width=500, bg='lightblue')
        self.main_frame.pack()

        self.result = tk.StringVar()
        self.result.set("Cow=0\nBull=0")

        self.start_button = tk.Button(self.main_frame, text='start', font='Broadway 15', command=self.entry_box)
        self.start_button.place(x=200, y=175)

        self.results = tk.Label(self.main_frame, textvariable=self.result, font='Broadway 20', bg='lightblue',
                                fg='darkblue')
        self.results.place(x=200, y=0)

    def entry_box(self):
        self.start_button.destroy()
        self.user_guess = tk.Entry(self.main_frame, font='Bradly 12', width=25)
        self.user_guess.insert(tk.END, '0000')
        self.user_guess.place(x=150, y=150)
        self.start_game()

    def start_game(self):

        user_input = self.user_guess.get()
        num = [int(cypher) for cypher in user_input]
        counter = 0

        game_playing = True
        while game_playing is True:
            digit = [random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(4)]
            cow, bull = 0, 0
            for i in range(4):
                if num[i] in digit:
                    if num[i] == digit[i]:
                        cow += 1
                    else:
                        bull += 1
            counter += 1
            print("Turn {}: cows = {}\t bulls={}".format(counter, cow, bull))

            if cow == 4:
                print("digit = {}\t num = {}".format(digit, num))
                game_playing = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = MainGame()
    game.mainloop()
```

First thing: do not use global imports (`from tkinter import *`). Instead use `import tkinter as tk`.

Then let's look at your `entry_box`: the function as you defined it takes no argument, but then you expect it to delete the `start_button`: the only reason this works is because the function is defined in the same script, but as soon as you move it to another script for example, it will fail. You did the same with `result`, which is defined in the main body, but then used in `game`, and for the `win` variable used to set the `user_guess` Entry widget.

The solution for this is to 1) reformat your code to account for these changes, which can work for something this small 2) use global variables, but this is usually considered a bad practice, because as your code grows it becomes a pain to track them down (plus many other reasons) 3) use classes, which is what I did here.

So here is what I did: I create a class, and in the `__init__` I put the things I want to have available when the script starts, or that I generally want to use throughout the game: the main frame where I will place the widgets, the results or the start button.

Then the `entry_box` function: You see that I pass just self: since the start button was defined as `self.start_button` in the `__init__`, there is no reason to pass it as an argument, because it is already stored in `self` as an attribute. Same with the `main_frame` where I put the `Entry` widget.

Lastly the `game` function: here, I make sure that the comparison between `num` and `digit` is between `int` numbers. Then if the comparison fails, I draw another random list of 4 elements for `digit` and repeat. The results are printed in the terminal.

This is by no means perfect, and you can easily improve it in a few ways:

1) the comparison between the lists can be easily made faster and shorter with `numpy`;
2) I did not update the `results` widget. You should be able to do it with what I told you here.
3) I assume you want the user to input the `user_guess`. You just have to modify a bit this code

Hope it helps!